# The Cython module is not an IPython extension

Tags: ipython, cython, jupyter-notebook

When trying to load Cython extension from my Jupiter notebook

```
%load_ext Cython
```

I get the below message:

> The Cython module is not an IPython extension

I did not have this problem a couple of weeks ago, when I wrote a Cython extension on my nb. I have tried to upgrade ipython and cython both from my regular environment (I am using a Mac running 10.11) and from Anaconda, with no success. Any tips?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try a lowercase cython, as in `℅load_ext cython`

Comment: Have you created a file called `Cython.py`? It might be shadowing the `Cython` module you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cython is not an IPython extension, so `%load_ext` won't work on it.  You can still use `import cython`.